# Is there a way to introduce a preinstall step like the one in npm for installing deno packages in a deno project?

Tags: npm, deno

So npm allows a preinstall script to run before installing a module. For example, puppeteer uses this step to install headless chrome. Is there any way to do something like this with deno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Node.js, Deno has no package manager. Instead of installing packages, all modules and dependencies are simply cached as static files for use at runtime — there is no configurable hook for an "installation step". Any code which requires an external dependency (such as a coordinating process in the case of Puppeteer) must ensure that such a dependency exists at **runtime** using program code. See [Creating a Subprocess](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.3/examples/subprocess) in the manual.

> See also section 3.1 of the manual [Basics > Modules](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.3/basics/modules) for information about the module system.

---

For an example of a Puppeteer implementation in Deno, see [`https://deno.land/x/puppeteer`](https://deno.land/x/puppeteer) ([source GitHub repo](https://github.com/lucacasonato/deno-puppeteer)).